# Prove $\lim_{n}\sup{x_{n+1}\over x_n} < 1$ implies $\lim_n x_n = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence $x_n \ne 0$ such that:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup{x_{n+1}\over x_n} < 1
> $$
>   Prove: 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0
> $$

I would like to verify the below.

Let:
$$
y_n = \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}
$$
If $y_n$ converges, then:
$$
\exists\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup y_n = L \implies \exists \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup |y_n| = |L|
$$

Since $L < 1$, then $|L| \in [0, 1)$. Also:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup y_n < 1
$$
Thus:
$$
0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty}|y_n| \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup |y_n| < 1
$$
Therefore:
$$
0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right| < 1
$$

Which means $\exists N\in\Bbb N$ such that for $n > N$ the sequence of absolute values starts to strictly decrease. Thus:
$$
\exists N\in\Bbb N : \forall n > N : |x_{n+1}| < |x_n|
$$
But $|x_n| \ge 0$, then by monotone convergence theorem:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right| \in [0, 1) \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}|x_n| = 0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0
$$

Could someone please verify the proof above?

Comment: That is wrong, a counter-example is $x_n = (-2)^n$ with $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = -2 < 1$. Or do you assume $x_n > 0$?

Comment: @MartinR Nope, I did not assume that. By your counterexample, the above is indeed wrong.

Comment: Note that $L < 1$ does *not* imply $|L| \in [0, 1)$.

Comment: Your last edit changes the problem completely so that my answer does not apply anymore. I suggest that you revert to the original version and ask a new question for the updated problem. Alternatively please unaccept my answer so that I can delete it.

Comment: @MartinR But your answer is the one I was looking for, why do you want to delete it? As it does apply to the problem. Thanks to you and José Carlos Santos I've figured out the problem was incorrectly stated in the book. And that is the only thing reflected in the update to the question along with some thought from your answer. Of course, I can unaccept your answer if you still insist.

Comment: Then change your question back to the original version.

Comment: @MartinR Ok, I've reverted the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is *wrong,* a counter-example is $x_n = (-2)^n$ with
$\limsup_{n\to\infty}{x_{n+1}\over x_n} = -2 < 1$.

There are several flaws in the proof:

- $y_n = \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ is not necessarily convergent.
- $\limsup y_n = L$ does not imply $\limsup |y_n| = |L|$, a counter-example is $y_n = -2 + (-1)^n$.
- $L < 1$ does not imply $|L| \in [0, 1)$, a counter-example is $L=2$.
- If $|x_n|$ is monotone decreasing then it is convergent, but not necessarily against zero.

You'll have to require that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left|x_{n+1}\over x_n\right| < 1$ instead. Then (as José already pointed out),
$$
 0 \le |x_n| \le c^{n-n_0} |x_{n_0}|
$$
for some $c \in [0, 1)$ and $n \ge n_0$, and $x_n \to 0 $ follows.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is wrong because you only proved that, if $n$ is large enough, then $\lvert x_{n+1}\rvert<\lvert x_n\rvert$ and that is *not* enough to deduce that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$, even if you mention the monotone convergence theorem, which has nothing to do with this.

Since $\limsup_n\left\lvert\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right\rvert<1$, if $c\in\left(\limsup_n\left\lvert\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right\rvert,1\right)$, then $\left\lvert\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right\rvert<c$, if $n\geqslant N$, for some $N\in\mathbb N$. So, $\lvert x_{N+1}\rvert\leqslant c\lvert x_n\rvert$, $\lvert x_{N+1}\rvert\leqslant c\lvert x_N\rvert$, $\lvert x_{N+2}\rvert\leqslant c^2\lvert x_N\rvert$, and so on. Therefore, by the squeeze theorem, $\lim_nx_n=0$.

Comment: I do not see the assumption $\limsup_n\left\lvert\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right\rvert<1$ in the question.

Comment: I assumed that that's wht the OP meant by the expression $\lim_n\sup$.

Comment: @MartinR I was actually thinking that $\lim\sup_n \left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right| < 1$ follows from $\exists \lim\sup_n\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < 1$. Do you mean that assumption is wrong?

Comment: @roman: Again, $x_n = (-2)^n$ is a counter-example.

Comment: @roman I suggest that you edit your question, replacing $\limsup_n\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ with $\limsup_n\left\lvert\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right\rvert$.

Comment: @MartinR well there are no other constraints on $x_n$ in the source of the problem except for those listed in the question section. Those are just $x_n \ne 0$ and $\lim\sup_n \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < 1$. This might be a mistake in the book.

Answer (score 1):

The one weak step is when you go from the limit of the ratio $\left|\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right| < 1$ to the statement that $|x_n|$ eventually becomes monotone decreasing.

That step is true, but at the level of a proof, I think you need to justify *why* it must hold.